# how does phase mechanism works in UVM?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm trying to understand UVM phasing mechanism especially in connect_phase().

```
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(14) @ 0: e2.c1.gc1 [connect] phase
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(14) @ 0: e2.c1.gc2 [connect] phase
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(39) @ 0: e2.c1 [connect] phase
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(14) @ 0: e2.c2.gc1 [connect] phase
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(14) @ 0: e2.c2.gc2 [connect] phase
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(39) @ 0: e2.c2 [connect] phase
UVM_INFO testbench.sv(62) @ 0: e2 [connect] phase
```

Not like build phase, in connect_phase, the connect phase executed from bottom-up.
Someone says that it's not the matter after build_phase() done. But in hte every single simulation, I can see the bottom-up way.

I think there is some special or inevitable reason to do that, would you please help me for understand Why a connect phase and else phase in a UVM execute from bottom-up except build and finish phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically the `build_phase` is a *breadth-first* ordering. The ordering of the `build_phase` is dictated by the fact that the parent's `build_phase` creates its children, so naturally the parent must execute its phase before the children's phase.

You should only concern yourself with the ordering *between* phases, not ordering between components within the *same* phase. The `connect_phase` only requires that the components you are connecting have been constructed first and does not care about the order you make connections.

You might want to read [this discussion](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/calling-build-phase#reply-48493) about phase ordering with an attached example for more details.

Comment: That's not breadth-first. Breadth-first would be `e2, c1, c2`, like build phase is executed. This is more like reverse depth-first.

Comment: I have one quick question for this The connection between the sequencer and driver is done in the agent, and normally this connection would be present in the connect_phase. What would happen in this scenario if connect phase was top-down?

Comment: @TudorTimi, that is what I meant to say. Corrected

Comment: @Monica, The ordering of the connect_phase does not matter. When you cal the `connect()` method from within the `connect_phase()`, it is actually just a request for a connection. At the end of the connect_phase() the UVM figures out the correct ordering to make connections based on the export/port directions.